# Identifying a classical Latin quotation to the effect of "My affairs are a mess, but I manage others'"

Tags: classical-latin, passage-identification

I recall a  Latin quotation I encountered some years ago, *ex memoria*  in John Gray's Lawyer's Latin, but I don't have the book to hand and can't find the source of it.  It was something to the effect of "My affairs are a mess, but I manage those of others": does anyone have a source of this quotation and it in the Latin original?

Comment: Welcome to the site! It seems that you have created two accounts by accident. I recommend registering your account and [following these instructions to merge them](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts); that gives you full access to and benefit from both the question and the answer. I look forward to seeing more questions and answers from you!

Answer (score 9):

Horace, Satires, II  3. 19: *Aliena negotia curo, Excussus propriis*